# Right align wrapped text but otherwise left align

Tags: css, text-align

I am making a mobile web application to display church hymns. A verse in a hymn should ideally not be broken into two lines when it exceeds the width of the screen, but it cannot be avoided with varying mobile screen sizes.

Instead I would like to have text, that's is wrapped to a new line, be right aligned.

How do I with CSS ensure that wrapped text is right aligned and where the text otherwise is left aligned.

Screenshot of how I want the result to look like: 
[image]

Here is my HTML:

```html
<p>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br/>
 Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br/>
 Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<br/>
 Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</p>
```

Comment: I can't think of any layout method, text or otherwise, that would do that.

Comment: Too bad `text-align` is not applicable for `:first-line` (otherwise it could work using that, if the text was split up into individual lines/elements.)

Comment: I went with a javascript solution: https://jsfiddle.net/691uzhn5/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can make each verse in a tag and use `text-align-last`. The problem is the poor compatibility (no mobile nor safari).

```css
p {
  -moz-text-align-last: right;
  text-align-last: right;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
<p>
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
```

You can see values and compatibility in MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last

Comment: Does not completely solve my problem. Lines that are shorter than screen width will be right aligned. Maybe I could fix this with some javascript.

Comment: @AndreasJoensen Yeah, all **last** lines will be aligned to the right side, and if there's a single line obviously that behaves as last line. It's hard to accomplish what you need exactly. With javascript you need to cut the strings and this is not bulletproof. Come here again if you need more help. Good luck.